# Templates on Coda

Tags: html, templates, coda

I'm trying to move away from Adobe Dreamweaver and now that Coda 2 is out with lots of new features, I have the perfect candidate :D

The only feature I need and can't find an equivalent in Coda is the ability to create templates and files dependent on it. To set editable regions and when the template is updated, all the code gets updated in all the files except for the editable regions.

Is there a way to do this seamlessly on Coda 2 or with plugins / external tools?

I need this to html only pages, on .php files I do it by `including(header and top phps)`...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

That feature is not available in Coda. But like you said, when using PHP, you can just use includes to pull in common content. Using HTML only, there is not really an elegant way to deal with this. Is there a reason why you can't just use PHP files instead?